# Make user choose how many threads he want?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm trying to make a C# tool where the user can choose how many threads he want for the tool to execute at the same time.
So for example he put "10" in the threadsTextBox so when he will click the startButton the program will start and will execute the needed task on 10 threads at the same time.

Here is the current code I have for 3 threads, but I don't know how to make the user able to choose how many threads he want the program to use.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doStuff());
    Task task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doStuff());
    Task task3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doStuff());

    Task.WaitAll(task1, task2, task3);
            Console.WriteLine("Done !");
}

static void doStuff()
{
    // do stuff here
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't. Users choose poorly. Use the task parallel library, and have it decide how much parallelism to use.  It's good at that. Typically you want to add threads until every processor is servicing exactly one thread and those threads are going flat out 100% all the time; the TPL will try to adjust to meet those conditions when given CPU-heavy tasks.

Comment: Also, I note that using threads correctly is one of the hardest tasks in modern programming, and you are having some difficulty with having the user input a number, which indicates to me you're a beginner. This is probably not a suitable task for a beginner.

Comment: You should also keep in mind that unless `doStuff` is processor intensive then you won't get a huge benefit from multiple tasks/threads. You should measure your processing time with different numbers of tasks running and see what benefit, if any, you get.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like an ideal use of arrays:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var tasks = new Task[n];
    for (int j1 = 0; j1 < n; ++j1)
        tasks[j1] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doStuff());

    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
            Console.WriteLine("Done !");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast response, so if I understand it correctly, 'j' will be the user choosed threads, right ?

Comment: No, `n` is the number of threads (and the number of array elements). There is no `j`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, my program will need to read each line of a text file and start a thread for each, imagine the text file contains 100 lines, will the threads continue creating and the program will only stop when it will have executed the task for all the lines, or will it only read the first 10 lines if the user choose 10 threads ? Thanks

Comment: That would depend on how you program the rest of your problem.

Comment: I'm gonna make an other question.

Comment: A Task is not a 1:1 to a thread.   All you are doing is limiting _how many tasks_ are created at a time not _threads_. You might fire up 4 tasks but due to the CPU specs, only 2 run at a time.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benwilli/2015/09/10/tasks-are-still-not-threads-and-async-is-not-parallel/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to allow the user to enter the number of threads as a command-line argument.

```
int numberOfThreads = int.Parse(args[0]);
```

In this example I use `Enum.Range` to generate an IEnumerable with the right number of elements, then use LINQ to start the tasks.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int numberOfThreads = int.Parse(args[0]);
    Task.WaitAll(
        Enum.Range(0, numberOfThreads)
            .Select(
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doStuff())
            )
            .ToArray()
        )
    );
    Console.WriteLine("Done !");
}
```

Or you could just use [`Parallel.For`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd781401(v=vs.110).aspx), depending if you really need to have those Tasks.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int numberOfThreads = int.Parse(args[0]);

    Parallel.For(1, numberOfThreads, (i) => doStuff());
    Console.WriteLine("Done !");
}
```

If you need more iterations but want to limit the number of threads, you can use [ParallelOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions(v=vs.110).aspx). In this example I allow for 100 iterations, but only using the number of threads specified by the user.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int numberOfThreads = int.Parse(args[0]);

    Parallel.For(
        1, 
        100, 
        new ParallelOptions
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = numberOfThreads
        },
        (i) => doStuff()
    );
    Console.WriteLine("Done !");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, my program will need to read each line of a text file and start a thread for each, imagine the text file contains 100 lines, will the threads continue creating and the program will only stop when it will have executed the task for all the lines, or will it only read the first 10 lines if the user choose 10 threads ? Thanks

Comment: Enumerable.Range() returns IEnumerable<int>

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should use an Array with the Length the user wants and you just initalize every Element of the Array with your Task.Factory.StartNew(()); ? Hope this helps a bit ^^